# Unable to push a single string to an array without changing the string value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have component called `edit-customer` which is an **dialog window**, which will receive the injected object from other `component` and will display that injected object properties(name,email).Below is the component code.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm">
    <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.name"   placeholder="Name"  formControlName="name" >
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.EMailAddresses"   placeholder="Email Id"  formControlName="email" >
    </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-flat-button (click)="onEdit()">Save</button>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
import {Component, Inject,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'atd-edit-customer',
  templateUrl: './edit-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-customer.component.scss'],
})
export class EditCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  public editForm: FormGroup;
  public someContact: IContact; 

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: IContact,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              public customersService: CustomersService,
              ) {} 

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null],
      email: [null,[Validators.email],
    });
  }

  public onEdit(): void {
    this.someContact = this.editForm.value;
    this.someContact.EMailAddresses= [];
    this.someContact.EMailAddresses.push(this.editForm.value.email); <========
    this.customersService.updateContact(this.someContact);
  }
}
```

**JSON looks like this:**

```
export interface IContact {
  id:       string;
  name:     string
  emailId:  string[];
}
```

**Now the issue is:**

- When i hit the **SAVE** button without making any changes in the `email` input field, The **PUT** operation is not happening and i am getting this response:

[image]

- But if a make some changes in the  `email`  input field and hit the **SAVE** button, The **PUT** operation works fine.

I am pushing **email** like this:

```
this.someContact.EMailAddresses= [];
this.someContact.EMailAddresses.push(this.editForm.value.email);
```

What's wrong with the code ??

Comment: Do you want to push the `this.editForm.value.email` Id in `this.someContact.EMailAddresses` array?

Comment: Ya i want to push it to **this.someContact.EMailAddresses**

Comment: Now the push is working only if i make some changes in the `email` i/p field, even i didn't make any changes also it should `push`.

Comment: N how about API call is it getting called successfully?

Comment: Only if make changes in `email` then `api` call is successful, If not getting error as shown in the given image.

Comment: Have updated the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbbdev) try and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190416/discussion-between-shankar-and-prashant-pimpale).

Answer (score 1):

Really; your question isn't clear.

But as i understood; that you face an issue when the user press on **save** button without making any changes.

To solve this issue, you shouldn't use `ngModel` with `formControlName`; just one of them on the element.

**What does happen in your case?**

you set the default value of `email` control to be `null`, and it won't be filled through `ngModel`, so; if there's no new entered value it will stay `null`, until new value added.

**But i can see the value?!**

Yes; that filled from `ngModel`, not from the control.

Try this:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editForm = this.fb.group({
        name: [this.data.name],
        email: [this.data.EMailAddresses.,[Validators.email],
    });
}
```

And remove `ngModel` from the fromFields.

BTW, using `ngModel` with `formControlName` will cause an error in the newer versions of **Angular**.

Comment: Sorry the issues still persists.

Comment: Can you log someContact value?

Comment: Only if change f i didn't make any changes in `email` i/p field the issues is coming.

Comment: let me understand well, you cannot get email value if the email field doesn't change only?

Comment: The log looks like this: **EMailAddresses: Array(1)
0: ["jhon@gmail.com"]**

Comment: And what is the expected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190417/discussion-between-shankar-and-nimeresam).